# Using multiple Layouts or Templates in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I've been trying to setup gatsby with 2 templates and layouts (full-page and half-page) for at least 2 days now but neither are working, I only get a white page with no elements at all (except gatsby elements like *div#___gatsby* and scripts).
Here is the *src/templates/half-page.jsx* code

```
import React from "react";


export default class HalfPageTemplate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Half-Page</div>
                {children()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the *src/pages/index.jsx* page code

```
import React from "react";
import HalfPageTemplate from "../templates/half-page"


class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout location={this.props.location}>
                <HalfPageTemplate>
                    <div>avc</div>
                </HalfPageTemplate>
                <div>some text</div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: When you get a white page you should check for errors in two places: the web inspector console, and the output (STDOUT) from your `gatsby develop` process. 99% of the time you'll find the error in one of those.

Comment: No error in `gatsby develop` terminal output, all are `Compiled successfully`, I totally forgot about the web inspector console, it has at-least 5 errors, I'll investigate it and post the solution. Thanks you @coreyward for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/templates` is a Gatsby specific folder (it expects files there for gatsby-node.js) so maybe that’s messing things up. Move your file as a test. Secondly you have to use `this.props.children` not `children()`

Comment: It seems like I just needed to use {this.props.children} instead of {children()} and now everything is working great, thanks, please update your answer so I can accept it.